# jQuery dataType

Tags: jquery, json

timeout works! but when timeout I want to run a function. do you have any ideas?

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
url: "xajax.php", 
timeout: 100, 
data: "name=John&location=Boston", 
success: function(msg){ alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); }
```

Comment: Does the server return `json`... ?

Comment: It is hard to pinpoint the problem without the response. Most of the time the issue is bad json. Can you go to `xajax.php?result=hello` in the browser and add the response to your question?

Comment: response is a Javascript alert box "parseerror"

Answer (score 1):

Probably your json object response is incorrect, check it for example in: 
- http://jsonlint.com/

you could check it too in your browser console/network specs to see if it is in client or server side.

You could display what you are sending from server ( after create json object) in order to see if you are sending correctly.

Comment: i dont want to create JSON. now response is alert box "Data Saved: John" i  $.ajax({
    url: "xajax.php",
    type: "GET",
//    dataType: "json",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
 timeout: 40000,
    success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
});

Comment: but now; timeout doesnt work!

Comment: ok, well if you are specifying dataType:json, you must receive a json object which you create in server side, this timeout will start when you make ajax call, if you are printing now your response and u get correct result, which I think is : "John" then time out wont applied, there cause you are receiving it before time ends.

Comment: thanks viruskimera. you are right. I decreased timeout to "100". It works. but when timeout I want to run some functions. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You could add a error function after success one, error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");call function Here;
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }

Comment: $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "xajax.php",
   timeout: 100,
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }

 error: function(x, t, m) 
 { if(t==="timeout") 
 { alert("got timeout");
alert("time is out"); }
  else { 
    alert(t); 
    } }

Comment: it doesnt work because my codes dont include json dataType. your error  is available for json response!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
url: "xajax.php", 
timeout: 100, 
data: "name=John&location=Boston", 
success: function(msg)
    { 
    $("#result").html("here is result: "+msg);
    }
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus)
    { 
    if (textStatus == "timeout")
        {
        $("#result").html("TIMEOUT!");
        }
    }
 });
```